# If a number is a multiple of 3, write to the console: "Hi" plus the number e,g IT3

Tags: c#

how can I make the code below work?

If a number is a multiple of 3, write to the console: "Hi" plus the number e,g IT3

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter number that is a multiple of 3");

int[] numero = new int[5];

numero[0] = 3;
numero[1] = 6;
numero[2] = 9;
numero[3] = 12;

numero = Console.ReadLine();

if (numero = "3, 6, 9, 12, 15")
{
   Console.WriteLine("IT" + "{0}");
}
```

Comment: You don't need to explicitly declare any multiples of 3.. just calculate them, as you would in "real life". If I asked you if 28,752 was a multiple of 3, you (probably) aren't going to have it memorized; You'll most likely need to work it out mathematically.

Comment: Also, you say you want to write "Hi" but you actually write "IT". You might want to clear up those requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there's a few things going on with your code.

You're using `=` (should be == to compare as a single equality sign is assigning a value) on a `string` type ("") quotations define string types.

What you want to do is test each index of the array using integer comparison, or if you're going to read them as strings use the string comparator `.Equals()`.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter number that is a multiple of 3");

int[] numero = new int[5];

numero[0] = 3;
numero[1] = 6;
numero[2] = 9;
numero[3] = 12;

numero = Console.ReadLine();

if (numero = "3, 6, 9, 12, 15")
{
    Console.WriteLine("IT" + "{0}");
}
```

The above code should be translated to something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter number that is a multiple of 3");

int[] arrCheck = new int[5];

arrCheck[0] = 3;
arrCheck[1] = 6;
arrCheck[2] = 9;
arrCheck[3] = 12;

int number = 0;
number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

//if the number is a multiple of the value stored in arrCheck[0] (e.g 3)
if (number % arrCheck[0] == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hi" + number);
}
```

The [modulo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/remainder-operator) operator is useful for checking remainders and in this case if the remainder is 0 post division with 3 then you know it's a multiple.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [% Operator.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/remainder-operator)

> The remainder operator % computes the remainder after dividing its
>   first operand by its second operand.

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(numero) % 3 == 0)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: @Captain Wibble - That works perfectly.. Thank you!

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: That's helpful as well.

Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter number that is a multiple of 3");

var numero = Console.ReadLine();

if (Convert.ToInt32(numero) % 3 == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"HI IT{numero}");
}
```